# how to make next and previous button in monocle ebook reader using this codes?

Tags: javascript, filereader, monocle

I created this function for next and previous button, in other words there are 2 buttons in my html page and when i click next or previous the pages in the monocle will also move accordingly,
i read that i have to use a custom page flipper for this but they have not provided an example of how to create one.

this is what i've tried and fails:

```
function fileSelected(event,str) {

    var thefile = document.getElementById('file');
    var tval = thefile.value;
    var ext = tval.split('.').pop();
    var files = event.target.files;
    var fname = tval.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();


   if (ext == "epub" || ext == "EPUB"){
        function createReader(bookData) {
            Monocle.Reader("reader", bookData);
        }
        new Epub(files[0], createReader);

   }else if(ext == "htm" || ext == "htm" || ext == "html" || ext == "HTML"){

        var bookData = {
            getComponents: function () {
                return [
                    fname
                    ];
            },
            getContents: function () {
                return [
                    {title: "test", src: fname}
                    ]
            },
            getComponent: function (componentId) {
                return {url:componentId};
            },
            getMetaData: function(key) {
                return {
                    title: "Test documents",
                    creator: "Aron Woost"
                    }[key];
            }
        }
                window.reader = Monocle.Reader('reader', bookData);

   }else{
        return false;
   }


}
function next(){    
    Monocle.Reader('reader', {}, {}, function (reader) {
      reader.moveTo({ direction: 1 });
    });
}
```

when clicking next will give an undefined error in my console.

any idea as how to implement a custom page flipper?

https://github.com/joseph/Monocle/wiki/Page-flippers

I am not that savvy in JS. sorry :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in this block of variable declaration:

```
var thefile = document.getElementById('file');
var tval = thefile.value;
var ext = tval.split('.').pop();
var files = event.target.files;
var fname = tval.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
```

Is there any input field with 'value' property applicable, like `<input type="text" id="file">` ?

You sure the filename will certainly have a dot in it, i.e. extension?

Also `event.target.files` looks suspicious.

If there's nothing wrong, please tell which line the console shows error at. You can double click on the error  to have the erroneous line highlighted.